# How to change UIScrollView contentOffset animation speed?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, core-animation

Is there a way to change contentOffset animation speed without creating your own animation that sets the contentOffset?

The reason why I can't create my own animation for contentOffset change is that this will not call -scrollViewDidScroll: in regular intervals during animation.

Comment: Assuming calling `[scrollView setContentOffset:foo animated:YES]` from within an animation block doesn't work (and I suspect it doesn't), you can probably access the animation duration by messing with "private" APIs - e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11271360/349112) gives a way to change the deceleration rate. Here be dragons...

Comment: hi, please see my revised answer below.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately there is no clean and easy way to do that. 
Here is a slightly brutal, but working approach:

1) Add `CADisplayLink` as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
```

2) Animate content offset:

```
CGFloat duration = 2.0;

// Create CADisplay link and add it to the run loop
self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(_displayLinkTick)];
[self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = newContentOffset;       
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Cleanup the display link
    [self.displayLink removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}];
```

3) Finally observe the changes on `presentationLayer` like:

```
- (void)_displayLinkTick {
    CALayer *presentationLayer = (CALayer *)self.scrollView.layer.presentationLayer;
    CGPoint contentOffset = presentationLayer.bounds.origin;
    [self _handleContentOffsetChangeWithOffset:contentOffset];
}

- (void)_handleContentOffsetChangeWithOffset:(CGPoint)offset {
    // handle offset change
}
```

Comment: I think step 3 is the important one to have in mind: the current state of the UI is given by the presentationLayer.

Comment: @kamilkocemba This is an amazing tip in general! It's actually a really efficient way to use a single animation to drive the positions of other elements. Thanks!

Comment: Its works. But any button on UIScrollView does not receive touch event.

Comment: But… what do you do in `_handleContentOffsetChangeWithOffset`?

Comment: @buildsucceeded, The same code you have in your `scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

Comment: Interesting use of the `presentationLayer`.

Comment: This works great with `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` to animate a view controller that's using autolayout (the two don't play nicely together).  Animate a dummy UIView's frame, and track the presentation layer to update the view controller's frame.

Comment: https://codegists.com/snippet/swift/moscrollviewswiftswift_tkirby_swift

Swift class with

func setContentOffset(contentOffset: CGPoint,
        with timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction,
        duration: CFTimeInterval)

I added it as an answer but some busybody mod deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

To get periodic information about the scroll state, you could run the animation in steps.  The delegate will get called once (scrollViewDidScroll:) for each step

```
- (void)scrollTo:(CGPoint)offset completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {

    // this presumes an outlet called scrollView.   You could generalize by passing
    // the scroll view, or even more generally, place this in a UIScrollView category
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;

    // scrollViewDidScroll delegate will get called 'steps' times
    NSInteger steps = 10;
    CGPoint offsetStep = CGPointMake((offset.x-contentOffset.x)/steps, (offset.y-contentOffset.y)/steps);
    NSMutableArray *offsets = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i=0; i<steps; i++) {
        CGFloat stepX = offsetStep.x * (i+1);
        CGFloat stepY = offsetStep.y * (i+1);
        NSValue *nextStep = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(contentOffset.x+stepX, contentOffset.y+stepY)];
        [offsets addObject:nextStep];
    }
    [self scrollBySteps:offsets completion:completion];
}

// run several scroll animations back-to-back
- (void)scrollBySteps:(NSMutableArray *)offsets completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {

    if (!offsets.count) return completion(YES);

    CGPoint offset = [[offsets objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
    [offsets removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    // total animation time == steps * duration.  naturally, you can fool with both
    // constants.  to keep the rate constant, set duration == steps * k, where k
    // is some constant time per step
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self scrollBySteps:offsets completion:completion];
    }];
}
```

Call it like this...

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);    
[self scrollTo:bottomOffset completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

// BONUS completion handler!  you can omit if you don't need it
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code solved my issue

```
CGPoint leftOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
          [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                                delay:0
                              options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                           animations:^{
                               [self.topBarScrollView setContentOffset:leftOffset animated:NO];
                           } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Not working for me. Setting 0.1 doesn't make it faster.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a simple solution that works.

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [self setContentOffset:<offset> animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope this helps.

Brian

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried setting a different duration, and its still about 500 ms.