# UITableView/UIScrollView altering the speed of bounce after finger lifts up

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

When I scroll past the top cell (going up) in my UITableView, I release my finger and the UITableView returns back to it's original position with a nice bouncing animation. Is there any way to change the speed with which it scrolls back into the original position?

What I want to do is the following, if you pull the table down further then some 'x' threshold value of contentOffset, I want the table view to bounce back into original position **faster** than default.

Answer (score 2):

`UIScrollView` has a `decelerationRate` property that you can use. There is also a constant that you can set it to: `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast`

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm adding this:     self.tableView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast; to my viewDidLoad of my tableviewcontroller.

Comment: Not sure when the default is set. But I thought you were going to set it as part of `scrollViewWillEndDragging...`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't have any noticeable effect there either.

Comment: Have you tried any different values for the rate? Debugged to check the value is set and retained.

Comment: According to this answer you can't change the value to anything but defined constants. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8711525/233700 May be I can achieve the same thing by manipulating the contentOffset property?

Comment: You should be able to run an animation to a specified content offset with a specified duration, yes.